# Problem with tinymce and list-items

Tags: list, tinymce, bbcode

I am having a problem with using the bbcodeplugin and list-items. While the lists are being safed as bbcode as i want it, when reopening and editing the text, tinymce adds additional markup to lists, so that something like

```
<ul>
<li>one</li>
</ul>
```

becomes

```
<ul>
<ul><li>one</li></ul>
</ul>
```

So each `<li>` item is being wrapped with an additional `<ul>` which I would like to prevent.

How could I possibly exclude all list-items from being modified by the tinymce-javascript?

---

This issue seems related to the "tinymce adding BR when inserting code" thing, which I now saw several times during my research. because not only the ul tags are added by tinymce, but also br's.

Please, can someone give me any hint?

Comment: Haha, great - finally i found the solution for this issue, a simple oneliner, to be added into the tinymce-init:

apply_source_formatting : false

So this option set to false prevents tinymce to add such unwanted markup.

Comment: `apply_source_formatting` just made harder to edit HTML directly but didn't solve the problem

Comment: I have this problem too, and `apply_source_formatting: false` not working

Answer (score 0):

You should add the parameter on init.

> apply_source_formatting : false

This will prevent any preformatting of the source.