# tinymce makes invalid nested lists

Tags: html, tinymce

Is there a way to get tinymce to generate valid html?  It's generating lists like this:

```html
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <ul>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <li>text</li>
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <ul>
                <li>text</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

[Unicorn](http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/) outputs:

> Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context.

I'd prefer lists like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>
        text
        <ul>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>text</li>
            <li>
                text
                <ul>
                    <li>text</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was happy to find that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6096506/869653) solved the issue (setting `source_formatting` to `false` when initializing tinymce); however it seems when tinymce parses some markup (for example if you put some in a textarea and then initilize tinymce) tinymce re-parses it as in example 1. Any ideas on how to make tinymce not change the markup originally in the editor I initialize it on?

Answer (score 8):

Add the lists plugin when initialising TinyMCE

```
tinyMCE.init({
...
plugins : "lists",
...
});
```

**Edit:**  I believe this only applies to TinyMCE 3.x

Comment: Still needed in Tinymce 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Check the latest version 3.4.4. It should be fixed there.

Comment: It's not fixed in 4.2.8 :(

Answer (score 0):

try setting option,
`fix_list_elements : true`  in init method.