# Nested list oddities from TinyMCE with Diazo

Tags: tinymce, plone, diazo

We have a website running Plone 4.3 and Diazo to theme it. One of our content editors reported this weird issue. He was editing a page on our website involving nested lists: an ordered list with indented bulleted lists on certain items.

The code is formatted correctly on the unthemed version (sans Diazo) of our website, and looks correct when you look at the HTML view in TinyMCE (while editing). When it outputs through Diazo, though, the list tags get jumbled. Here's the code:

[The "correct" version (from in TinyMCE and unthemed version)](http://bit.ly/HrRQvw) —

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <ol>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
<ol>
    <ul>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ol>
```

[The weird version (through Diazo)](http://www.caes.ucdavis.edu/admin/resources/aes/reeport/copy_of_proposal-checklist) —

```
<ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <ol> 
    </ol> 
</ol> 
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<ol> 
</ol> 
<ul>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Actually I just saw that [TinyMCE fixes this in version 3.4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917944/tinymce-makes-invalid-nested-lists) (it outputs the real correct code, with the nested list within the `<li></li>`) — but is there a reason Diazo is doing this? The XML rules pulling this code through aren't targeting the lists at all, just the parent container (.main .content).